# Azure api or sdk to get list of app registrations and the certificates associated with them

Tags: python, azure, api, rest

I want to connect my python application to azure.

**Problem statement:**
Get a list of apps registered with their certificate thumbprints and expiry details.

I tried a lot but can't find any APIs. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [`Microsoft Graph API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) for that.

The API operation you would want to use is [`List applications`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). The information about the certificates associated with each [`application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) will be available in [`keyCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/keycredential?view=graph-rest-1.0) attribute in the response.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. If I need to call this api from python what headers will it need?

Comment: Please see this link regarding using Graph REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0. You may also want to look at [microsoftgraph-python](https://pypi.org/project/microsoftgraph-python/) package though I don't think this package is from Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav. Btw, do we need to create a fresh bearer token always. Does it expire in some time?

Comment: Typically bearer token expires in an hour. What you should do is make use Azure SDK Identity package as mentioned by @Sven below for handling of tokens. Among other things, it will also take care of renewing the tokens automatically if it has expired. Once you get the token, you can pass that token to your REST API requests in your code.

Comment: Ok thanks. I tried using the SDK but the credential I get is not a bearer token. How do I change that to the token as it won't work with my requests in python

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Azure SDK](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-python/) for this. For Authorization check out the [Identity Package](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-identity/1.7.0/index.html).

Do you want to host your app in Azure as well? Then you should use Manged Identity. Alternatively, create a service principal for your app. This must get the read rights to the app registrations.

If you use the SDK, you only need a credential object that is created with Tenant ID, App Id and Secret (Service Principal). See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate

Basically I recommend you to use the SDK instead of calling the GRAPH. The SDK takes a lot of work from you ;)

Comment: Sven - I don't think Graph API is supported in Azure SDK for Python. It only supports Azure related services.

Comment: I think it possible with phyton: https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-graphrbac/0.61.1/azure.graphrbac.operations.html#module-azure.graphrbac.operations.service_principals_operations

Returns the Service Principal
https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-graphrbac/0.61.1/azure.graphrbac.models.html#azure.graphrbac.models.ServicePrincipal

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it is for Azure AD Graph. Microsoft is in the process of deprecating it I believe: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/graph-rbac?view=azure-python.

Comment: @sven does the sdk have any package which can help me in uploading a certificate from the program?

Comment: It should be but i never used it. I guess you have to check the docs. ;/. In C# there is a function in the SDK to upload a cert.