# How to get bearer token from Azure SDK DefaultCredential

Tags: python, azure, rest, identity

Problem :

I need to get a list of certificates of apps registered under Azure AD and renew the ones which are expiring.

I was able to get the apps related details through Microsoft Graph API > applications. But, the issue is the bearer token refreshes every time in 1 hr. Since I want this task to be automated, I need to create a fresh token always.

I got some reference of Azure SDK for identity-based authentication but the package function is returning a credential, not a token (bearer token) to be used inside the rest API header **Authorization**

Code:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
```

References:

[Azure api or sdk to get list of app registrations and the certificates associated with them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69611028/azure-api-or-sdk-to-get-list-of-app-registrations-and-the-certificates-associate)

Comment: Can you share the code you are trying to use?

Comment: juunas - I have added the code.

Comment: Ayush - It might be beneficial if you provide some context in your question (like linking your previous question here) so that folks trying to answer your question can understand what you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ah, thanks Gaurav. I will add the context here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a lot of debugging and surfing the internet, I was able to find the RestAPI way to get the bearer token.

```
    data = {
        "client_id":"add your client id",
        "scope": "add scope ex: User.read Directory.read.All",
        "grant_type": "password", [don't modify this one since you are providing the password]
        "username": "your username",
        "password": "your password",
        "client_secret": "client secret"
    }

    headers = {
        "Host": "login.microsoftonline.com",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    data = requests.post(f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token', data=data, headers=headers)
```

You will receive a json consisting of access token and related details.

Do remember to provide the permissions in the azure portal> Azure AD > app registrations > your app > API permissions (grant consent)
: )

Comment: Please check [`DefaultAzureCredential.get_token`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet). HTH.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. I was facing some issue in that that's why had to move with RestAPI : (